# Find out directory size considering replication in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, replication

Is there any way to find out raw HDFS space consumption by a directory. As far as I know

`hdfs dfs -du -s /dir`

shows `/dir` size not considering replication of inner files.

Answer (score 2):

Run the command `hadoop fsck /dir` and look for the parameter `Average block replication`. Multiple this number by the result you have from `hdfs dfs -du -s /dir`.

Comment: Unfortunately the estimation is too rough.

Comment: `hdfs dfs -dus /dir` shorcut